# how to export a Pocket's list of articles with the tags?

Tags: pocket

I'm using the python api and successfully exporting the list with all the articles in my Pocket. It has all the information about the articles, apart from the tags I gave to every article.

Does anyone know how to get a list of all the articles with their tags? doesn't have to be through the api specifically.

Comment: Did anyone solve this? Looking at the documentation it should be responding with this info...